# Sql Server DateAdd Does not Display Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that's suppose to select one of my column if the date inside the column is not expired (the date expires after one hour, see query below). So here is my query and my display with the opposite condition (The field timeForgot is underlined in red, but that seem to be functional) :

[image: Query with the opposite condition]

```
select DATEADD(HOUR, 2, timeForgot) as Expiration, timeForgot as ReceivedAt, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as Now
from forgot_password
where DATEADD(HOUR, 2, timeForgot) > Convert(smalldatetime,timeForgot)
```

But when I apply the right condition, the output show nothing even it should display some fields. Could anyone tell me what's wrong with this query?

[image: Query with right condition but no output]

```
select DATEADD(HOUR, 2, timeForgot) as Expiration, timeForgot as ReceivedAt, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as Now
from forgot_password
where DATEADD(HOUR, 2, timeForgot) < Convert(smalldatetime,timeForgot)
```

Comment: Please include the query as text in the question.

Comment: because there are no rows where `Expriation` is smaller then `ReceivedAt` ?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple this

```
 DATEADD(HOUR, 2, timeForgot) < Convert(smalldatetime,timeForgot)
```

Is never true.

What exactly did you expect this line to filter out?

Maybe you mean

```
DATEADD(HOUR, 2, timeForgot) > Convert(smalldatetime,timeForgot)
```

That would be similar to your first query.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bothering you, I've found my answer, It was kind of a mess in my head, the query that I did want to achieve was this one :

```
    select DATEADD(HOUR, 2, timeForgot) as Expiration, timeForgot as ReceivedAt, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as Now
from forgot_password
where DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, timeForgot) > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```